# call CodeDom generated method

Tags: c#, codedom

I need to dynamically execute a method entered by the user.  CodeDom seems the best way for this, but I can't figure out how to call a method of the user code from my code.

The user code will compiled and then the method called multiple times.

User Method Code (could be any code, with multiple parameters but returns a bool)

```
public bool YesRun(double var1, double var2)
{
  return (var1 / 2) > var2;
}
```

My code

```
if (/*CompiledCodeDom.YesRun(size, weight)*/)
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: I know how to do this, but I need more restrictions about the user's input. Can you explain your use-case in deep?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code "ScriptEngine" that works great, takes care of all of the details me.  Was also easy to use.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30999/ScriptEngine-User-Defined-Calculations-in-C-VB-JSc